# Styling in react based on scroll position

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, position, styles

I cant figure out solution for changing the style of particular element, based on its scroll position in react

I have responsive card made in react-bootstrap, with scrollable content inside, and I would like to dynamically change its subtitles style, when they'll reach the proper height of their  container.

What is the best and simpliest  way to achieve that?

Here is my render:

```
render() {
return (
<Card className="bioCard" text="white">
  <div className="cardWrapper">
   <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{this.props.cardTitle}</Card.Title>
   
    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
     {this.props.cardSubtitle.sub1}
    </Card.Subtitle>
    <Card.Text>{this.props.cardText.text1}</Card.Text>
   
    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
     {this.props.cardSubtitle.sub2}
    </Card.Subtitle>
    <Card.Text>{this.props.cardText.text2}</Card.Text>
    
    <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
    <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>

  </Card.Body>
  </div>
 </Card>
);
```

}

and CSS:

```
 .card {
 width: 35rem;
 height: 85%;
 align-self: center;
 }

.cardWrapper {
margin: 20px 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code you already have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Of course, sorry. I've added it to my previous post.